# MySQL - Using update/set with like from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, set, sql-update, sql-like

I am trying to update one column called 'Name' in one table using the naming conventions from another table.

My script below is not working and I am not quite sure why... Either get a syntax error or another way I tried to do this I ended up with all the 'Name' as NULL:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Name = 
ISNULL(
    (SELECT TOP 1 CorrectSSPname
    FROM table2
    WHERE UPPER(Name) LIKE  '%’ + UPPER(WrongSSPname) + ‘%')
    , Name
    )
WHERE DATE >=  '2018-07-01'
```

I can get 'like' to work using the following script for a single update but unable to do multi updates using the script above:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Name = 'xxx'
WHERE Name like 'yyy'
```

Comment: Are these `’` (note: that's no ordinary single quote!) characters in your original query too or did that just happen when you copied it to here? (You didn't write the query in an office document editor like Microsoft Word by any chance?)

Comment: Is the mysql tag the right one? Looks a bit more like SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like this:

```
UPDATE tabel1 tbl1
LEFT JOIN table2 tbl2 ON UPPER(tbl2.WrongSSPname) LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(tbl1.Name), '%')
SET tbl1.Name = tbl2.CorrectSSPname
WHERE tbl1.DATE >= '2018-07-01'
```